# how to include a directory in the package debuild

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, debian, packaging

a Simple Debian package would be created in following steps, the following steps would be tutorial for beginners

consider i have a file lets say test.sh which would just print test on the screen

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "this is sample debian package created " >&2
```

What should be the output after installing the debian package?
A)I want to place the above file which i named as test.sh in /home/bla/Desktop/ after installing the package using "dpkg -i test-1.0.deb"

In order to achieve above process follow the below mentioned steps as it

```
mkdir test-1.0
cd test-1.0
#in order to place test.sh in /home/bla/Desktop, simply create the same directory structure in the test folder using this command

mkdir -p home/bla/Desktop/
cp test.sh home/bla/Desktop/
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
mkdir DEBIAN
cd DEBIAN
```

add the control file with following contents

```
Package: test
Version: 1.0
Section: devel 
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Depends:  bash
Pre-Depends: no
Recommends: no
Maintainer: test <test@test.test>
Replaces: no
Provides: no
Description: A sample testpackage in order to demonstrate how to create debian packages
```

Package is ready come outside of test folder and enter dpkg --build test-1.0/

your package is ready and you can install it by using dpkg -i test-1.0.deb

If i want to do the same process with dh_make and debuild, i was unable to add the directory structure where i wanted my test.sh to be placed after installation

steps which I followed:

1. `mkdir test-1.0`
2. copy the directory structure as above

   ```
   cd test-1.0/ && mkdir -p home/bla/Desktop/
   cp test.sh home/bla/Desktop/
   ```
3. `dh_make -n -s -e test@test.com`
4. `cd debian`
5. `rm *.ex *.EX`
6. `cd ..`
7. `debuild -us -uc`

no mater what my test.sh is not at all included in the package after, i donot know what is the reason that is what i have understood from debian manual

can any one know to do it, please let me asap.., i just want to know how i can include the files in the package when building debian package using debuild/dpkg-buildpackage like i have done in the first process which is very simple

Comment: Don't include user home directories in the package itself (it is an awful idea), put your executable in standard location (e.g. `/usr/bin`) and create a link to it (or better create .desktop file) with `postinst` script instead.

Comment: that was an example, i need to create a package which places all the files inthe respective folders like test1 in /tmp/test, test2 in /usr/test2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Q/D example utilizing ***dh**** ***and dpkg-buildpackage***:

*1)* Pepare working directory and test file (we are going to package *"foo"* script which should be installed to *"/any/dir"*) :

```
mkdir test-0.0.1
cd test-0.0.1
echo -e "#\!/bin/sh\necho \"hi, i'm foo\"" > foo
chmod +x foo
```

*2)* Create simple *Makefile* which will handle installation:

```
binary:
    # we are not going to build anything

install:
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/any/dir
    cp foo $(DESTDIR)/any/dir
```

*3)* Generate package skeleton:

```
dh_make -i --createorig
```

*3a)* Optionally adjust debian control file

*4)* Build the package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -A -uc
```

*5)* Test generated package contents:

```
dpkg-deb -c ../test_0.0.1-1_all.deb | grep any

drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-12 20:54 ./any/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-12 20:54 ./any/dir/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root        30 2012-06-12 20:54 ./any/dir/foo
```

---

***Edit:*** Example without using *Makefile* (if you are not going to *build* anything):

*1)* Create test data:

```
mkdir test-0.0.1
cd test-0.0.1
mkdir contents
touch contents/a
touch contents/b
```

*2)* Create package skeleton:

```
dh_make -i --createorig
```

*3)* Create ***debian/test.install*** file with following contents:

```
contents/   /usr/share/mycontents
```

*4)* Build package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -A -uc
```

*5)* Examine built package:

```
dpkg-deb -c ../test_0.0.1-1_all.deb | grep contents

drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-13 11:44 ./usr/share/mycontents/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-06-13 11:38 ./usr/share/mycontents/contents/
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2012-06-13 11:37 ./usr/share/mycontents/contents/a
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2012-06-13 11:38 ./usr/share/mycontents/contents/b
```

Comment: thank you so much, what if i have hundreds of files can i include a tar ball of contents and later copy the contents in postinst scripts..any other alternative other than Makefile

Comment: @user1430462: add `cp yourdir/* $(DESTDIR)/` to Makefile or see edit for Makefile-free example :)

Comment: i am bit childish can i use any other file than makefile, somehow i am afraid of makefile i have exactly 1145 files to be copied, i was thinking to copy the contents in tmp folder later copy all the files in respective positions using postinst scripts, but worrying what if i need to update the files, i need to consider few things where i loose the default updation of debian package, any how thanks for the excellent tutorial

Comment: @user1430462: by no means you want to do this with `postinst` scripts, just describe proper directory bindings in `debian/$packagename.install` file.

Comment: but as i have told you there are 1145 file how can I write all those, it would easy for me to create a tar archive and copy the contents in postinst what say, any how i will try with .install file

Comment: @user1430462: that would be no different than just giving the user the *.tar itself... The essense of package manager is that any file installed is registered in the system and debs are compressed too. Where are you getting difficulties with `$pkgname.install` file?

Comment: no difficulties in install file i did not tried yet, can we have a a complete directory copied at one in make file like cp yourdir/* $(DESTDIR)/ ,  and cp test/etc/* $(DESTDIR)/etc/*

Comment: @user1430462: considering the 2-nd example, all files in directory `contents` (including sub-directories) would be installed to `/usr/share/mycontents` on the target system.

Comment: i last query i have already made a package which is working perfectly, which i have built using dpkg --build <package name> can i use that package in any way to build package with debuild ?

Comment: @user1430462: I guess, no direct conversion would be possible. By the way, if you include configuration files in your package, don't forget to register them in `debian/conffiles`, otherwise they will get overwritten on package update.

Comment: yup thanks for information, but when i use dpkg -c test it does,not include any files of the source , i am goona try once again....

Comment: hey what if i need to copy the files to /usr/local/bin, it gives me error, as according to the http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/modify.en.html, i cannot copy files to /usr/local/bin , any thoughts ?

Comment: @user1430462: generally, you shouldn't package anything that goes to `/usr/local/*` (it is dedicated for local software exclusively); for 3-rd party applications you should rather choose `/opt/*`.