# How to prepare commercial 'Debian source package' for myApp (Debian software center) without source code?

Tags: linux, debian, software-packaging

The 'Debian source package' (.dsc, .tar.gz, .changes etc combined in a compressed file) can be build using 'debuild' command. Is it possible to prepare such package without source code? What should I write in debian/rules file?

Edit: Just for now, I used 'dh_make' and 'debuild -us -uc' commands and that works fine (all files are created as expected and .deb works fine). For that, I commented some lines in debian/rules file that has '$MAKE' and changed debian/control file as I needed.

Comment: It makes no sense to provide a source package without sources. Can you elaborate on where the requirement comes from?

Comment: @Helmut Thanks 4 reply :) :see 'Commercial and proprietary software' at http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/my-apps-packages/

Comment: And here is the ans of this question!

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11002142/2706918